# Table with many rows and repeating images - fontawesome or cached image?

Tags: caching, font-awesome

My site has many large tables with hundreds of rows. In some cases, each row had a thumbs up, thumbs down, and a check mark img. Though the images are cached, each one required a download before it could be cached, so I thought replacing these images with fontawesome CDN would save 3 img downloads per user.

Was this a stupid mistake, that is, does every instance in the table of the e.g. thumbs up (even though it is the exact same thumbs up) require a trip to the fontawesome server? In other words, did I actually cause my site's performance to decrease by implementing the fontawesome CDN in these tables?

Answer (score 1):

Fontawsome is a single css and font file, the css has directions to place a particular character from the font into the page. Once your browser has downloaded the fontawsome font and css files, it will then use them for whatever fontawsome icons you have on the page, much the same as it uses the standard arial font (or whatever) for each character on the page. So this is probably a good thing to do. Having said that the size of the fontawsome font and css files may be more than the total image sizes , but  it is pretty compact so i doubt it.

Basically you have replaced 3 image downloads with 1 css and 1 font download. so look at the size of these to make sure they are smaller.